# Tools to bound the singular values of a finite sum of random matrices from below?

Tags: lower-bounds, linear-algebra, randomized-algorithms, matrices, chernoff-bound

[Matrix Chernoff bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Chernoff_bound) (see also [this arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4389)) are usually used to give upper bounds on the largest eigenvalue of a finite sum of random matrices. Sometimes it can also be used to give a lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue of a finite sum of random *positive semidefinite* (PSD) matrices.

For PSD matrices, the eigenvalues are the same as the singular values. My question is:

> Is there any tool, or any other special cases (apart from the PSD case) for which there is a tool, to obtain lower bounds on the singular values of a finite sum of random matrices, or random symmetrical matrices?

Comment: [Crossposted](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089639/439) on Math.SE. Please do not crosspost the same question, on mutliple StackExchange sites at once. Otherwise, welcome!

Comment: This question is interesting, but potentially borderline for being on-topic: Chernoff bounds and bounds on singular values are clearly of interest in computer science (as are algorithms to compute them), but analytic upper/lower bounds on strictly mathematical objects would seem more a proper subject of mathematics. Perhaps this would be better answered on Math.SE.

Comment: or also [mathoverflow.se]